# Consuming .dylib from a server runtime

Tags: objective-c, macos, compilation, dylib, dyld

I have a requirement where I have to get the compiled code dynamically from the server and execute them from the OS X application. In short, the idea is to have few classes and methods in the compiled code(it can be a .dylib, .a or a bundle) hosted on a server, and the application downloads it form the server and accesses those classes dynamically. The completed code might contains HTML, javascript, Objective-C, or Swift.

Option 1. Static library 
It has to be part of the consuming application at compile time, so i think we can rule this option out.

Option 2. Dynamic library
I am struggling here, is it possible to download the dylib form the server and copy them in one of the application folders, and run from there dynamically using `dlopen`. is it possible?

Option 3. Bundle
I did not look into this yet, but the idea is similar to dylib.

Option 4. any other possibilities..

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can download a dylib. Why should that be impossible?

Then you can store it in one of the paths the dynamic linker is looking for. This is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryUsageGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001928-SW21).

Even I did not test it, I do not know, why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I do not want to save the dylib outside of my app, I tried few methods, like saving in one of the in-app folders, but had problems while loading the library run time.

Comment: Did you set the environment variables as described in the link I provided? You can set them with the info.plist file. It is the key `LSEnvironment`.

Comment: the link you provided says... "These environment variables are set only for apps launched through Launch Services. If you run your executable directly from the command line, these environment variables are not set."

Comment: The link I provided does *not* say that. At least, I cannot find it. Please link it. Maybe you searched for `LSEnvironment`, what I did *not* link. These variables are only set via launch services. It is obvious why it is that way and it is obvious what you have to do, if you start it from cli: Set it you own. You do not need the info.plist.

Comment: yeah, you are right.. here is the link.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-106825

Comment: Yes, I found that by searching your citation. However, if you start it from cli, set the environment var manually (or using a script or whatever to set an environment var).